# Cmd + Click for multiple-cursor is not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Cmd + Click to drag multiple cursors into existence.

However, when I select "Switch to Cmd+Click for multiple-cursor" it doesnt work, instead Alt + Click works to create multiple cursors which is odd.... then when I switch it back to "Switch to Alt+Click for multiple-cursor" neither Cmd + Click and Alt + Click work. I believe this is because the default settings in the JSON file has editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt". I can't edit the file because it's in read-only mode which I don't know how to change. I've been at this for over 4 hours now so I would appreciate anyone's help on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What machine are you on that has both Cmd and Alt?  A PC normally has Ctrl, Alt and Win; and a Mac has Ctrl, Cmd and Option.

Comment: what do you mean "when you select"? you mean when the menu item currently says "switch to cmd+click for multiple-cursor"? or after you click the menu item that said that?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: - I am using a macbook pro with an iclever keyboard which has the cmd button
- yes, when I click the menu item "switch to cmd+click for multiple-cursor" it still doesn't work
- Here is the output for my Help: About and yes the problem occurs even when i disable extensions:




Version: 1.85.2 (Universal)
Commit: 8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681
Date: 2024-01-18T06:40:32.531Z (2 wks ago)
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 26354273
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 23.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around, and I found out that the `defaultSettings.json` file isn't supposed to be edited by you. This is because these are the "factory" settings for vscode, so if you ever mess anything up, you can always refer back to this.

Instead what you need to do open your user settings json file. You can do this in vscode by clicking on the search bar, then pasting in `>Preferences: Open User Settings`. Then add the line `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",`.

If this doesn't work, then try deleting the contents in the `settings.json` and copy-pasting the contents from `defaultSettings.json` into `settings.json` (note that this will factor-reset your settings). Then replace the `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt",` with `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",`

Comment: this doesn't work for me..... does it matetr that i'm using an iclever keyboard for my mac? I do have it set to mac configurations.

Comment: It shouldn't matter as long as the key you are pressing is mapped to the cmd key on Mac. Are you sure you tried doing it to the details I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type "settings"
3. Click on `Preferences: Open user settings (JSON)`
4. Search for `editor.multiCursorModifier` (if it does not exist --> default: `alt`) and modify as you expect. For more https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multicursor-modifier